# Tomcat-embed-core library have Rapid Vulnerability :CVE-2023-44487

Tags: security, tomcat9

Tomcat-embed-core library seems like have high Rapid Vulnerability with CVE-2023-44487, cannot find any immediate mitigation for resolving this. Details available in [nvd link](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-44487)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got fixed
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.81

We can use that.